# VS Code Settings Sync: How to import local backup?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I've had issues with the native settings sync from VS Code. I got it to work across multiple devices again (using Github, not Mictosoft account). However, none of the extensions, keyboard shortcuts, themes etc. are activated/installed on my machines. The logs show successful operations and the correct files are downloaded into the local sync folder `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\sync`

Therefore, how can I get VS Code to recognize/load those local files? Currently, they're simply being ignored. In other words. Sync works but the downloaded settings are not active in VS Code across machines.

Any idea?